# Overriding equals() and hashCode() in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

All,

I have defined my class and which to override equals() and hashCode () methods as well. But I have no idea of what specifically these methods should be implemented for my own class. Can anyone please shed some light on the implementation of these methods for custom classes?

Comment: That actually depends on how you define equality. Often all or nearly all attributes need to be considered, sometimes only one / a few, and sometimes (think of Threads for example), all you want in your equals() method is to compare identity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say you already know which one of your custom classes need to override hashCode/equals? Then you also know what attributes (global variables) determine equality of each class.

When you know these attributes you can implement hashCode/equals either manually or by generating the methods using a modern IDE such as Eclipse, NetBeans, etc. In Eclipse there's an option named "Generate hashCode() and equals()" under the "Source" menu

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For equals, the answer depends on what your business need is, i.e. what does it mean for your objects to be equals.

hashCode() should always return a unique value for an object, unless that object is equal to another object. It should depend on the values of the properties on your object.

Comment: most importantly, hashCode() must *not* return different values for objects where equals() returns true

Comment: @michael good point, editing answer..

Comment: It can not always return a unique value. It is easiest to make it depend on the same properties as `equals`.

Comment: You can have only 2^32 different hash codes, but I can think of a lot more different Strings. They can't **all** have **unique** hashCodes.

Answer (score 2):

[Java theory and practice: Hashing it out](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html)

Comment: This answer is a link to a page on IBM that is returning back a 503 page.  Do you think you could update your answer to include the relevant information instead of being just a link?

Comment: @MichaelT This link is still active....

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you want to store an object in a collection (Map, Set, List) then **you have to implement equals and hashCode methods according to the contract defined in the documentation**.

Otherwise, many collection implementations won't have the expected behaviour. For implementation clues, read the Object Javadoc for [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashcode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Comment: Only *keys* in a hash must define the hash code correctly.  I can store my Froboz objects in a HashMap with no override of the `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods if I'm using, say, a `String` as the key, and with String, the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation are already correctly defined.

Comment: True. But  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object) will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Read the API documentation of the two methods in [`java.lang.Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). It describes *very* exactly how overriding implementations should behave.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing equals() make sure you understand the difference between equality and identity.
Two object instances may be 'equal' but may not be identical.
a.equals(b) is a test for equality, which your business rules should define.
== is a test for object identity (same object instance)