# When to include what?

Tags: java, hashmap, comparable, compareto

I created a class `Person` (as the book says) to hold the name and last name of a person entered from the keyboard and then there is another class `PhoneNumber` which encapsulates the country code, area code and the number of a person as a String.
Person is intended to be used as the key in a Hashmap.
Class `BookEntry` encapsulates both `Person` and `PhoneNumber`. A lot of `BookEntry` objects make up a HashMap that represents a phonebook.

`Person` implements `Comparable<Person>` so it contains `CompareTo(Person)` method. Later the book adds `equals(Object anotherPerson)`method.
My question is, isn't the `CompareTo` method enough for comparing two keys? or is it that the internal mechanics of the HashMap<> requires me to include `equals()` method to compare two keys?
**compareTo()**

```
public int compareTo(Person person) {
    int result = lastName.compareTo(person.lastName);
    return result==0? firstName.compareTo(person.firstName):result;
}
```

**equals()**

```
public boolean equals(Object anotherPerson){
    return compareTo((Person)person)==0;
}
```

Comment: Parameter to `equals()` need not be always a Person or its subclass.

Comment: Your `equals()` implementation is not complete. You have to check wether the parameter object is actually of type `Person`.

Comment: I know. If I pass a `String` , the program crashes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compareTo()` method  is used in sorting,

This method's implementation will determine who is greater(lesser, same) between two person, also at what degree

while `equals()` & `hashcode()` will be used in Hash based data structure (HashMap) in your case

> user-defined class as a key of HashMap

yes you need to implement `hashcode()` and `equals()` properly

**Also See**

- [overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919331/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: so basically, If i am using a user-defined class as a key then it **must** have an `equals()` and a `compareTo()` method to be used by internal mechanics, if i get it correctly :)

Comment: _user-defined class as a key_ of `HashMap` yes you need to implment `hashcode()` and `equals()` properly

Comment: You must not necessarily have an equals() methods. By default, equals just uses == for equality, which is fine for a great number of cases.

Comment: @Polygnome not really See :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581913/integer-wrapper-class-and-operator-where-is-behavior-specified

Answer (score 2):

Some data structures will use `compareTo` (for example a `TreeMap`) and some will use `equals` (for example a `HashMap`).

More importantly, it is strongly recommended that `compareTo` and `equals` be consistent, as explained in the [`Comparator` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

Another hint, found in [`TreeMap` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, **must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface**.

Finally, if you override `equals` you should also override `hashcode` to prevent unexpected behaviours when using hash-based structures.

Comment: so If I do not know which data structure uses what, I can use a combination of both, as in my case :)

Comment: @FasihKhatib Yes, if your class implements `Comparable`, it is good practice to override `equals` and `hashcode` consistently with your `compareTo` implementation. It will save you head scratching bugs later on. But your class **does not need to implement `Comparable`** to be used in a `HashMap` if that's your question.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` uses `equals()` and not `compareTo()`, so you have to implement it.
`TreeMap` uses `compareTo()`.

Comment: but for `equals()` to work, I need `compareTo()` . makes sense now :)

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need `compareTo()` for `HashMap`. You need `equals` and `hashCode` to be consistent. That is all.

Comment: Either you write the code in `compareTo()` and call it from within `equals()` or you write the code directly in `equals(). What is important is that your `equals()` should work properly.