# Using equals() in compareTo()?

Tags: java, equals, compareto

Test code (just to comply [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), obviously there's much better ways to rock your own case-insensitive data models)

```
public class TestClass implements java.lang.Comparable<TestClass> {

    public String test;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestClass o) {
        if (o == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return equals(o) ? 0 : test.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.test.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o == this) ? true : o instanceof TestClass ? test.equalsIgnoreCase(((TestClass) o).test) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return test.toLowerCase().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Say, I want my class implementing `Comparable` to follow the 'strong recommendation' [suggested](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) in the API:

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)).

Would it be OK then to use `equals()` inside `compareTo()`? Of course we are ensuring that `equals()` will not be calling `compareTo()` in return.

Similar: [When to include what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912914/when-to-include-what)

Comment: I'm asking about the use of equals() in compareTo(), not to discuss when to use equals() or compareTo(). ;) I'm also not delving into the implementation of equals() and  and compareTo() in the String class, that is out-of-scope here. The test code is really just to visualize how equals() may be used inside compareTo().

Comment: It’s ok but by the way: do not write things like `a? true: b? c: false`. That’s an obfuscated expression for `a  ||  b && c`. I.e `return o==this || o instanceof TestClass && test.equalsIgnoreCase(((TestClass) o).test)` will do the same.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! :) I knew something was fishy when I was typing out true/false... Great catch here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be ok as long as you are doing a NPE check before calling equals() inside compareTo().

One more point would be before doing

```
test.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.test.toLowerCase());
```

you must also check if test is NULL because "someString".compareTo((String)null) will throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! :)