# Check if list contains any item of another list in java

Tags: java, list

We have two lists one is of type `Question` and the other of type `Tag`.

The Question class has those attributes

```
private String id;
private String header;
private String content;
private List<Tag> tags;
private Long timeStamp;
```

The Question list has several questions in it and the Tag list has all tags in it.
We wanna check if One question contains any tag of the tag list.
I want to do this for all questions.

With `question.getTags`, I get the list of tags.

I tried

```
List<Question> allQuestions =  ... ; // List of type questions
List<Tags> alltags = ... ;  // List of type tag

for(Question question: allQuestions) {
    for(Tag tag: allTags){
        if(question.getTags().contains(tag)) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

This is not quite doing what I want to do, I think I have to do something with streams but I could not quite figure out how I exactly have to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing the operation for **every** tag that's in the list instead of once per question if **any** tag is in the list.

As you proposed, using streams could make this solution easier:

```java
allQuestions.forEach(question -> {
    if (question.getTags().stream().anyMatch(tag -> allTags.contains(tag)) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Note - this still has an O(m * n) runtime complexity, where m is the number of questions and n is the number of tags. You can optimize this to an O(m + n) runtime complexity by creating a `Set` from the list of tags so that the `contains` operation has an O(1) time complexity.

Comment: This could be good, one more thing when it matches how I could add that that tag which matches to a list for example

Answer (score 1):

Apache commons have an utility method for that: [CollectionUtils#containsAny](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#containsAny-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Question> allQuestions =  ... ; // List of type questions
List<Tags> alltags = ... ;  // List of type tag

for (Question x : allQuestions) {
    List<Tag> questionTags = new ArrayList<>();
    questionTags = x.getTags();
    questionTags.retainAll(allTags);
    // questionTags will retain common tags between allTags and x.getTags()            

    for (Tag tag: questionTags) {
        // Execute when there is at least one common tag
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all tags that contain in `alltags` list and their occurrence map

```
Map<Tag, Long> map = allQuestions.stream()
                           .flatMap(q -> q.getTags().stream())
                           .filter(t -> allTags.contains(t))
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Then you can add this list in another list if you want.
And recomend you to make a set for `alltags` then it will faster since `allTagsSet.contains` takes `O(1)` only.

Comment: Here now  you get number of  appearance  for each tag in map value

Comment: It is not quite working tho, it is counting wrong and some tags are not even in the map

Comment: @yassoplaya are you define equals and hashcode for Tag  class ?  If not then it will not work as map key.

Comment: I do not understand what you actually mean

Comment: To understand why you need to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894377/understanding-the-workings-of-equals-and-hashcode-in-a-hashmap
  and why it's not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871929/objects-as-map-keys-without-hashcode-and-equals

Comment: hashCode() and equals(Object o) methods are needed to overridden Tag class to use as Map key.

Comment: Ah, I understand, how do I override those ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919331/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```java
for(Question question: allQuestions) {
    for(Tag tag: allTags){
        if(question.contains(tag)) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Or are you asking whether the a given question contains a token from the question.tags() list?

Comment: How is that different than the loop in the question, except that `Question` probably doesn't have a `contains` method?